# How do we conjugate the verb right next to the conjugated verb?

Tags: grammaire

How do we conjugate the verb right next to the conjugated verb? I know that we should use infinite next to the conjugated verb or preposition. For infinitive, if it's a pronominal verb ex : se promener. Do I write se promener or according to the subject in the sentence. For ex : Je veux ____ (se promener)
Will the answer be se promener or me promener?
Thank you.

Comment: This can be answered by any conjugation table. The [help section](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) explains what FL is about. [Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Bescherelle](https://conjugaison.bescherelle.com/verbes/se-promener). [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/francais/se%20promener/7112), [The-conjugation.com](https://www.the-conjugation.com/french/verb/se_promener.php), etc.

Comment: If your question was about the reflexive pronoun and not the verb, then maybe you should rephrase the title of your question, "conjugate" only refers to the verb, you don't conjugate a pronoun, you can say it changes.  You can also think about the meaning :  in English you'd say, for example, "I teach myself French", not "I teach oneself French".... the

Comment: _Je veux me promener_.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a sentence with a verb that is already conjugated, the verb right after is in the infinitive.

> Ex: Je veux manger.
>
> Ex: Je peux essayer?

Manger and essayer are in the infinitive form: I want to eat & can I try?

This said, when we have a reflexive verb (se regarder, s’habiller, s’aimer, s’asseoir, …), we conjugate the personal pronoun to the noun it links to.

Ex:

> Je veux *me* promener
>
> Tu veux *te* promener
>
> Il/Elle veut *se* promener
>
> Nous voulons *nous* promener
>
> Vous voulez *vous* promener
>
> Ils veulent *se* promener

I hope this helps!